# How do I work with table variables with multiple rows in SAP HANA DB?

Tags: sql, hana

In SQL sometimes it is easier and faster to use table variables.

I know I can't use insert to table var in HANA DB, but what would be the best practice to do something similar?

I tried using SELECT to populate the variable but I can't insert multiply rows.

Do I have to use temporary table instead?

I would like to have a table with some values I create, like the below example I use for SQL, such a way I can use it later in the query:

```
Declare @temp table(Group Int, Desc nvarchar(100))
    insert into @temp (Group , Desc )
        Values (1,'Desc 1'), (2,'Desc2 2'),  (3,'Desc 3'),  (4,'Desc 4'),  (5,'Desc 5')
```

In HANA, I am able to create the variable, but not able to populate it with multiple rows :(

Is there any best way to do so?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this help? https://answers.sap.com/questions/9612016/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "UNION"-approach is one option to add records to the data that a table variable is pointing to.

Much better than this is to either use *[arrays](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.04/en-US/cba8ef91ba944e37beb26eb8bd995c2f.html)* to add, remove, and modify data and finally turn the arrays into table variables via the [`UNNEST`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.04/en-US/4f12887c7941410d802a36c3f1a87a59.html) function. This is an option that has been available for many years, even with HANA 1.

Alternatively, SAP HANA 2 (starting with SPS 03, I believe), offers additional SQLScript commands, to directly `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` on table variables. The documentation covers this in ["Modifying the Content of Table Variables"](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.04/en-US/36f718be73e745ceae0530aa80850ce3.html). 
Note, that this feature comes with a slightly different syntax for the DML commands.

As of SAP HANA 2 SPS 04, there is yet another syntax option provided for this:
"[SQL DML Statements on Table Variables](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.04/en-US/226f2125b7ed4f4aabe731cfed029d7b.html)".
This one, finally, looks like "normal" SQL DML against table variables.

Given these options, the "union"-approach is the last option you should use in your coding.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to use some information from the documentation you've send, but in my case, the SAP Hana Version is a litle bit older, 1.X version.
So, I am trying to insert data into the table variable with the procedure and using FOR structure.  Since I select many different data and insert it into another table so I can compare it.

Answer (score 0):

For who else try to find about it, I found a "work around" that is to use the UNION ALL.

I add the first row, then I do a UNION on the table and ADD the second line, like below:

```
tempTable = Select 1 as "Group", 'Desc' as "Desc" FROM DUMMY;
tempTable = SELECT "Group", "Desc" FROM :AcctClassificacao UNION ALL Select 2 as "Group",
            'Desc' as "Desc" FROM DUMMY ;

Select * from tempTable
```

In this case, I will have the result:

```
Group   Desc
  1     Desc
  2     Desc
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do anyways.

Comment: Yeah, this one is not a good "workaround" - it's basically ignoring features that have been around for years.